# How to change the font size of Menu bar, popup and navigation bar in Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, fonts

The menu bar, popup and navigation bar are too tiny font in Chrome
[image: too tiny font in Chrome menu]

How can I change the font size?
I already tired settings>custom font
but that does not change menu font size at all

My display size is set to 2560X1440

I am using windows 10

and scaled up everything to 225% so that texts are visible. I don't have this issues in other apps or browsers, the problem persists only with Google Chrome menu fonts.

Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a DPI scaling issue. Chrome uses some system/OS related settings for the fonts of these UI elements... it would be nice if they didn't do that and had it be customizable like the rest of the in-browser/website fonts.

1. Go to the Chrome shortcut and right-click. -- if you are doing so from the start menu or taskbar; you will right-click on the app icon again (from the pop-up menu) to see 'properties'.
2. select properties option.
3. Open the "Compatibility" tab
4. click on "Change high DPI settings".
5. click the "Override high DPI scaling behavior" option
6. use drop down to select the dpi scaling behavior of the app.

you may need to play with your system settings and app override settings. but IIRC this is how it's done. more info and links below;

refs:

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-high-dpi-settings-classic-apps-windows-10-april-2018-update

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-scaling-issues-for-high-dpi-devices-508483cd-7c59-0d08-12b0-960b99aa347d

Comment: Try: (1) Another Chrome profile, (2) Settings > Advanced > Reset and clean up > Restore settings to their original defaults.

Comment: OP hasn't tried either solution (or at least they haven't reported back yet), but your solution didn't work on my desktop PC. On my machine it's an issue with DPI scaling, seemingly very similar to what OP is talking about - switching profiles didn't have any impact or effect on font size or DPI scaling.

Comment: Sorry, I intended to put this comment on the post itself. But thank you for answering.

Comment: it's all good. I was curious about your solution -- I didn't think it would work, because on a fresh install of chrome on a brand new machine, i ran into this font scaling issue; so it's unlikely that changing profiles would do anything... also, it really does seem to be a DPI scaling issue. nothing to do with chrome profiles, specifically... it was worth a try though!

Answer (score 1):

I removed the extension "Zoom for Chrome", restarted chrome- it fixed tiny fonts in tabs and dropdown menus.  I then reset desired font sizes in chrome settings and desired page zoom percent and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not normal to a well-installed Chrome version.

First, check if the behavior is due to any extension: In Chrome,
navigate to `chrome://extensions/`, disable all extensions and
restart Chrome. If the problem is gone, then enable the extensions
back one by one, checking after each one.

If the above didn't help, I suggest to uninstall Chrome using
[Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/),
checking for and deleting any leftover folders,
then installing the latest Chrome version.

Answer (score 0):

None of this stuff worked, and I removed my extensions, no joy. Was considering uninstall/reinstall but I then ran the Windows 11 Compatibility Troubleshooter and the bookmark and tab fonts were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Had issues with small tabs/menus in both (native) Windows File Explorer and Chrome (running on Windows 11). Tried several options, the one that seemed to have helped, was to toggle font size (increase, then decrease) via Windows Display settings > Scale > Text size: Increase + Apply - set back to small/original + Apply.